# How to stop Skype bot from converting ' to its ascii character?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, skype-bots

I have made a SKYPE bot using QnA Maker. I have also used liststyle button in QnA Maker tool to show users as options buttons to choose if there are more than one match to the queries keyword. In that button text if there is '(apostrophe) then in the button it is converted to its ASCII Characters. For example:

```
PM's is converted to PM&#39;s
```

In text response it is fine apostrophe is visible
What can I do to stop this?
[image]